# C# Three Interacting classes

Tags: c#, class

I'm basically a beginner so bear with me. I have to create 3 classes, one of which is main, the other two being a Library class and a Book class.

I've been given this code and cannot alter it.

```
public static void Main (string[] args)
{
   Library lib = new Library ();

   lib.AddBook ("C# programming", "Gesick", 4);
   lib.AddBook ("java programming", "Roth", 2);
   lib.AddBook ("C++ programming", "Franklin", 1);
   lib.AddBook ("unity programming", "Preston", 3);
   lib.AddBook ("graphics & multimedia", "Chastine", 5);
}
```

This is the code I'm writing.

```
class Library
{
    List<string> library = new List<string>();

    public string AddBook(string Name, string Author, int Id)
    {
        Book.name = Name;
        Book.author = Author;
        Book.id = Id;
    }
}

class Book
{
    public string name;
    public string author;
    public int id;
}
```

It's obviously not complete and I do want to try to complete most of it myself. My first question is if I'm on the right track. My next question for now is how would I print the Books given to me? I haven't made the AddBook method yet but what would it look like to add what is given to me and then print that information?

Comment: Your library should be `List<Book>` rather than `List<string>`. Your `AddBook` method should create a book and add it to the library

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were almost there. You have to create book objects with the `new` keyword before using them. Think of a class as an object template. It is not the object itself. Your library list must be of type `Book` in order to accept book entries.

```
class Library
{
    List<Book> library = new List<Book>();

    public void AddBook(string Name, string Author, int Id)
    {
        Book book = new Book();
        book.name = Name;
        book.author = Author;
        book.id = Id;
        library.Add(book);
    }
}
```

As @Ben has pointed out, a string must be returned from the `AddBook` method, if the method is of string type. Since it seems to make no sense here, I changed its type to `void` (meaning, it does not return a value).

---

Also the `Book` class should have [properties](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x9fsa0sw.aspx) instead of [fields](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173118.aspx). Fields should only be used to store private things. The idea behind properties is to hide implementation details and to forbid direct access to class fields from outside. A property is typically a pair of methods used to access a field: a getter method and a setter method. In Java, for instance, these are just two regular methods. C# has a special property construct containing both of these methods and allowing to access properties like fields:

```
private string name;
public string Name
{
    get { return name; }
    set { name = value; }
}
```

Note that C# identifiers are case sensitive. It is usual to use [Pascal case](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x2dbyw72%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) (fist letter upper case) for property names, type names (class names) and method names, but camel case (fist letter lower case) for fields, method parameters and local variables. Some programmers like to introduce field names with an underscore (e.g. `_name`).

C# has [auto-implemented properties](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384054.aspx) that create a hidden backing field and do the "plumbing" automatically. You can simply write:

```
public string Name { get; set; }
```

---

Assuming that you have used properties in your `Book` class, you can also use [object initializers](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384062.aspx) in order to initialize a book object

```
public void AddBook(string name, string author, int id)
{
    Book book = new Book{
        Name = name,
        Author = author,
        Id = id
    };
    library.Add(book);
}
```

---

To your second question: How to print the books?

You can loop through the list of books with a [foreach](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ttw7t8t6.aspx) loop

```
foreach (Book b in library) {
    // TODO: Print the book "b"
}
```

If your application is a console application, you can use the `Console.WriteLine` method for this.

Comment: If the method signature provides a ```string``` return, you have to return a ```string```.

Comment: @Eser ...or even a timed interview question

Comment: Thank you! I'm supposed to print them out from a menu generated in main. I understand that I should use the foreach loop, but how would I reference that list since main is a different class from Library?

Comment: Add a printing method to your `Library` class! So that you can write `lib.Print();` in your `Main` class.